# Callback from native Java to Unity's C# script high latency

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Unity Android project that use Usb OTG to communicate with a midi device. It working pretty well except there is ~1 sec of latency.

CallStack example :

Unity Script -> Java code -> Cpp code

I found this solution on the android github ([here](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/native-midi)) I just adapt it to work with unity :

I changed this function :

```java
 private void onNativeMessageReceive(final byte[] message) {
        // Messages are received on some other thread, so switch to the UI thread
        // before attempting to access the UI
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showReceivedMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }
```

To :

```java
    private void onNativeMessageReceive(final byte[] message) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "MessageReceived");
        midiCallback.MidiMessage(message);
    }
```

The midiCallback is an object of type MidiCallBack which is an interface :

```java
public interface MidiCallback {
    void MidiMessage(byte[] data);
}
```

On Unity side I have an class who inherits from MidiCallBack :

```cs
    public class UnityMidiCallBack : AndroidJavaProxy
    {
        public UnityMidiAndroidCallBack() : base("com.test.unitymidianrdoid.MidiCallback")
        {
            
        }
        
        public void MidiMessage(byte[] message)
        {
            Debug.Log("newMessage);
        }
    }
```

I do not undersand why there is latency.

Comment: can you specify where is latency? between you log in Java and Debug log in Unity?

Comment: Are you performing usleep or sleep in native/cpp code? The repo you [linked uses usleep(2000)](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/blob/main/native-midi/app/src/main/cpp/AppMidiManager.cpp#L105) 
However, it's not clear from this question if you also have this

Comment: There is latency when I quickly press different notes on my piano, they appears on my screen with a second of latency one after the other. I have already comment the usleep(2000) in the cpp code.

Comment: Nobody can help me ?